# T-SQL Count of items based on date

Tags: t-sql

To make the example super simple, lets say that I have a table with three rows, ID, Name, and Date. I need to find the count of all ID's belonging to a specific name where the ID does not belong to this month.

[image]

Using that example, I would want this output:

[image]

In other words, I want to count how many ID's that a name has that aren't this month/year.

I'm more into PowerShell and still fairly new to SQL. I tried doing a case statement, but because it's not a foreach it seems to be returning "If the Name has ANY date in this month, return NULL" which is not what I want. I want it to count how many ID's per name do not appear in this month.

```
SELECT NAME, 
   CASE 
     WHEN ( Month(date) NOT LIKE Month(Getdate()) 
            AND Year(date) NOT LIKE Year(Getdate()) ) THEN Count(id) 
   END AS TotalCount 
FROM   dbo.table 
GROUP  BY NAME, 
      date
```

I really hope this makes sense, but if it doesn't please let me know and I can try to clarify more. I tried researching cursors, but I'm having a hard time grasping them to get them into my statement. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only want to group by the non-aggregated columns that are in the result set (in this case, `Name`).  You totally don't need a cursor for this, it's a fairly straight-forward query.

```
select
  Name,
  Count(*) count
from
  tbl
where
  tbl.date > eomonth(getdate()) or
  tbl.date <= eomonth(dateadd(mm, -1, getdate())
group by
  Name
```

I did a little bit of trickery on the exclusion of rows that are in the current month.  Generally, you want to avoid running functions on the columns you're comparing to if you can so that SQL Server can use an index to speed up its search.  I assumed that the `ID` column is unique, if it's not, change `count(*)` to `count(distinct ID)`.

Alternative `where` clause if you're using older versions of sql server.  If the table is small enough, you can just do it directly (similar to what you tried originally, it just goes in the query where clause and not embedded in a case)

```
where
  Month(date) <> Month(Getdate()) 
  AND Year(date) <> Year(Getdate())
```

If you have a large table and sarging on the index is important, there some fun stuff you can build `eomonth` with `dateadd` and the date part functions, but it's a pain.

Comment: The database I'm pulling this from is 2008. I'm really sorry, I should have mentioned that in the question, but eomonth won't work.

Comment: See edit.  Your case where clause was fine, you just weren't composing the overall query correctly.

Comment: I feel like I'm really close using your edit, but it's excluding everything with a month of 5 and everything with a year of 2017, treating them as individual clauses. I've tried both with AND as well as OR, as well as putting parenthesis around them, which I thought would make them process together.

Comment: It should be `<>` not `like`.

Comment: When I switched it to OR, and used <> it worked perfectly. You are a genius, thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Name, COUNT(ID) AS TotalCount
FROM dbo.[table]
WHERE DATEPART(MONTH, [Date]) != DATEPART(MONTH, GETDATE()) OR DATEPART(YEAR, [Date]) != DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE())
GROUP BY Name;
```

Answer (score -2):

In T-SQL:

```
SELECT 
NAME,
COUNT(id)
FROM dbo.table
WHERE MONTH(Date_M) <> MONTH(GETDATE())
GROUP BY NAME
```

Comment: `Extract` is mysql, he specfically mentioned sql server.

Comment: yeah saw it after i pressed save; answer revised

Comment: What if the current date is "5/19/2017" and one of the rows is for "5/19/2016"?

Comment: add an and clause for year, but doesn't change too much